# Why does another computers wallpaper change if I change mine?

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 - I've noticed that if I change my wallpaper, it changes on another person's PC as well (To the same one).

Is that a Windows 10 thing? Maybe they were activated on the same licence? Or is this person's PC monitoring mine?

We're in a work environment.

Comment: Are you both using the same Microsoft ID to log in?

Comment: I don't know - Could that be it? Is there any way to check?

Comment: Yes it could be.  The design is so that any computer you log into using the ID is set up the same way...wallpaper, desktop icon, etc (it goes deeper, just making simple examples).   When you start up from powered down on these computers do you login?

Comment: If you're in a work environment you should probably be speaking to your company's IT support staff.

Comment: Yeah - We log in. @Techie007 we don't.

Comment: @NewAmbition do you both log in using the same details?

Comment: Are you talking about yourself logging in on different computers or someone else on another computer seeing their wallpaper change because you changed yours?

Comment: Close voters: This question just asks why it could behave that way, not how to muck up things for the IT people.  The exclusion on IT questions relates to things where we would be interfering with IT's responsibilities.

Comment: When you login are you both using the same user and pass.. Login screens can look different depending on setup option, but you're likely using the same Microsoft account, the concept is whatever computer you log into will have your settings because they are loaded from the Microsoft account.  It may have been setup that way for a reason, or it may just be because you appear to be a small company with no IT staff and whoever did it didn't realize the side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [settings app under `Accounts` click under `Individual sync settings`](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4077-sync-settings-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) the `theme setting` off.

[image]

Now Windows no longer syncs the theme/wallpaper.